# Running multiple extjs4 apps on a liferay portal page

Tags: extjs4, liferay

I'm using liferay portal for a website. All of my portlets are based on Extjs4 MVC framework. The problem is that when I add multiple Extjs4 based portlets to a page one of them won't load. I experimented with the app.js files of the apps. and found out that when I added the initialization code to one of the portlets all of them starts running.

for example following code works,

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext', '/loc-treeview-portlet/loc-treeview/ext-4.0/src');

//loader path for the first app

Ext.Loader.setPath('LocTree', '/loc-treeview-portlet/loc-treeview/app');

//loader path for the second app
Ext.Loader.setPath('ServiceTree', '/service-layer-portlet/service-treeview/app');

// Instantiate the apps which I have created by extending Ext.app.Application
Ext.create('LocTree.app.LocTreeApplication');
Ext.create('ServiceTree.app.ServiceTreeApplication');
```

But I can't do this in the actual portal because it's not known in advance which of the extjs4 apps will be in the page. Does any body have any idea of how to get these apps to work independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that document 'ready' event in ExtJS4 only initializes one app(portlet) in a given page. So what I did was to wrap all the code app.js file in an AUI().ready() call.

```
AUI().ready(function(){
     // all app.js code here

});
```

Comment: I don't know but it doesn't work. Unfortunately I don't have the time to dig through the details.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can extract the Application definition into the page template that way you know there is only one App launch event. Then each portlet is essentially a view with its own controller. You will need to call init() manually on the controllers though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply DmitryB. This is not possible because I don't know which of the portlets will be available on a given page in advance.